# Export Kendo grid data to multiple sheets of Excel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to export contents of kendo data grid to multiple sheets of Excel?

Comment: Can you please add the source code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: $("#patData").data("kendoGrid").saveAsExcel()  exports to one excel in one sheet what we need is separate some fields into one sheet and others  into another sheet in same workbook. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it can be, you may need to refer here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/multiple-grid-export. And you can separate the data sources and apply to the exporting.

Comment: I was looking at this example. In the example something like sheets[0].removecolumn that will do.         var sheets = [
        productsWorkbook.sheets[0],
        productsWorkbook.sheets[0]
      ];
Is there API to remove columns from sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Setup your grid to capture excel export event

MVC:

```cs
.Events(e => e.ExcelExport("onExcelExportGrid"))
```

or javascript

```js
"excelExport": onExcelExportGrid,
```

This javascript method will allow access to the workbook kendo will use to build excel file. This follows a very simple schema

```js
var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
  sheets: [
      {
          rows: [
              { cells: [ { value: "foo" } ] }
          ]
      }
  ]
});
```

To prepend a new sheet, use something like

```js
function excelPrependWorksheet(wb, worksheetName)
{
    var sheet = {
        "name": worksheetName,
        "rows": [
            { "cells": [] }
        ]
    }

    wb["sheets"].unshift(sheet);
}

function onExcelExportGrid(e)
{
    excelPrependWorksheet(e.workbook, "example");

    // fill out row and cells values here.
}
```

Supported fields for cells, sheets, and workbook are documented at https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/docs/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook.md